# Search irrespective vietnamese character vs english character

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search out results irrespective marked or unmarked.

For example: I want to find the words "rồng phượng", but when i typed "rong", "rong phuong", "phuong", "rồng phuong", "rong phượng"..., i all get right results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the `icu_folding` token filter:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": { 
          "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer",
          "filter":  [ "icu_folding", "lowercase" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then use a simple `match` query:

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "phượng"
    }
  }
}
```